# How can I bind to the property of a class from the codebehind?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

In my XAML I have this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Stats.Scores.Team}" Style="{StaticResource Column_Value_Large}" />
```

I need to be able to create that TextBlock, in it's entirety, in the codebehind. Here's what I have:

```
foreach (var Stats in player){
    var columnHeaderScore = new TextBlock
    {
        Style = Application.Current.Resources["Column_Value_Large"] as Style,
    };
    columnHeaderScore.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath("Stats.Scores.Team"),
    });
    columnHeaderStackPanel.Children.Add(columnHeaderScore);
}
```

However, the binding doesn't seem to be working. What's the appropriate way to set the binding in the codebehind?

**Edit for context:** my goal is to generate a bunch of these text boxes inside a big loop in the codebehind. See my revised example above which now shows the loop. Since I want to do it this way, I don't think there's any possible way for me to do it in the XAML; I would have to set the binding in the codebehind.

Comment: Do you get any binding errors in your output in Visual Studio? If a binding does not work, you should get trace logs of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

My problem was using "Path" in SetBinding instead of "Source". The working code looks like this:

```
foreach (var Stats in player){
var columnHeaderScore = new TextBlock
{
    Style = Application.Current.Resources["Column_Value_Large"] as Style,
};
columnHeaderScore.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding
{
    Source = Stats.Scores.Team,
});
columnHeaderStackPanel.Children.Add(columnHeaderScore);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you use xaml in a wrong way. Why don`t you set the`TextBlock`in the XAML code and bind its`Visibility`to a property or use a`Style`. Then you don`t have to create the binding in the codebehind.
EDIT: Why don't you use a ItemPanel or something like that to which you bind your collection and give it a DataTemplate which displays the TextBoxes?

Comment: I just added some context to my original post to explain why that is undesirable. I'll be creating a bunch of these text boxes via a loop in the codebehind, otherwise your answer would work.

Comment: I figured it out. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help!